# Get different columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, comparison

Lets supose that I have a table Table1(id INT, a text, b text, c text) and Table2(id INT, row0 text, row1 text, row2 text). I have some data on Table1 and I migrate it to Table2 (id->id, a->row0, b->row1, c->row2). Now, I want to check if all data is migrated and if the fields all Ok. I use this select in order to find the Id values that are wrong, but I don't know an optimus way to find out wich are the columns that are not ok, for example, I have the record Table1(1,hel,l,o) and the record Table2(1,he,null,o) I would like to know that the columns a/row0 and b/row1 are wrong

```
        SELECT Table1.id, Table2.id FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id WHERE
        Table1.a != Table2.row0 OR
            (Table1.a NOT NULL AND BI_EN.contract.Table2.row0 IS NULL) OR
            (Table1.a IS NULL AND BI_EN.contract.Table2.row0 IS NOT NULL) OR
        Table1.b != Table2.row1 OR
            (Table1.b NOT NULL AND BI_EN.contract.Table2.row1 IS NULL) OR
            (Table1.b IS NULL AND BI_EN.contract.Table2.row1 IS NOT NULL) OR
        Table1.c != Table2.row2 OR
            (Table1.c NOT NULL AND BI_EN.contract.Table2.row2 IS NULL) OR
            (Table1.c IS NULL AND BI_EN.contract.Table2.row2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is enough:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.a, Table1.b, Table1.c,
       Table2.id, Table2.a, Table2.b, Table2.c
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.id = Table2.id 
  AND (Table1.a != Table2.row0 
  OR Table1.b != Table2.row1 
  OR Table1.c != Table2.row2 )
```

Comment: That code doesn't work as expected because it gives me all columns, not just those that are not the same, and that's what I don't know how to get

Comment: your original query was to get only `id`s. you can't get different number of columns when you do sql query. any query always return the same number of columns. so if you need only record id - you can remove other fields from `SELECT` part.